# Probability of Poisson distribution of a random variable is 0

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution

Let $N$ be the pmf of a Poisson distribution, $Z$ be a nonnegative random variable, I read in the answer to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372403/showing-a-conditional-poisson-process-does-not-have-independent-increments) that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(N(Z)=0) &= \mathbb{E}\mathbb{P}(N(z)=0|Z=z)\\
&= \mathbb{E}e^{-Z}.
\end{align}

I get the first equal sign is by Law of total expectation, but I don't understand the second equal sign. Is $\mathbb{P}(N(Z)=0|Z = z) = e^{-Z}$? Intuitively, I can see
this equation is correct, but looking at the conditional part, I want to substitute the random variable $Z$ with the given constant $z$ and get $e^{-z}$. Also I tried to use the Bayes theorem, apparently it's wrong but I don't know where I got it wrong,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(N(Z)=0 | Z=z) &= \frac{\mathbb{P}(N(Z)=0, Z=z)}{\mathbb{P}(Z=z)}\\
&=\frac{\mathbb{P}(N(z)=0)}{\mathbb{P}(Z=z)}\\
&=\frac{e^{-z}}{f(z)}
\end{align}
Can someone help me understand this concretely? That would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That other post defines $N(\,.)$ as a Poisson ***process*** and ***not*** as the PMF of a Poisson distribution. We know that
$$
\mathbb P(N(t)=n)=\frac{\lambda^nt^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}\,.
$$
In particular, when the rate $\lambda$ is one,
$$
\mathbb P(N(t)=0)=e^{-t}\,.
$$
When $Z$ is a nonnegative random variable that is *independent* of $N$ then
$$
\mathbb P(\,N(Z)=0\,|\,Z\,)=e^{-Z}\,.
$$
From this
$$
\mathbb P(N(Z)=0)=\mathbb E[e^{-Z}]
$$
follows trivially by the tower property of conditional expectations.

The other post seems to neglect that $Z$ needs to be independent of $N$ and uses a confusing notation: $\mathbb P(\,N(Z)=0\,|\,Z\color{red}{=z}\,)$ is the deterministic function $e^{-\color{red}{z}}$ of which we do not have to take an expectation.